# Maven Properties Plugin Not Picking Up Values

Tags: maven, wildfly

I have a Maven project with a parent and 2 child modules (one child builds a JAR and one child builds a WAR with the latter dependent on the former). I have gotten the project to successfully use the WildFly plugin to run an application server. I am now trying to update that plugin to use property files instead of inline strings for the path to the WildFly server and to also have different environments via profiles. Below is what I have so far (a lot is testing code).

**local.properties**

```
local.wildfly.path=/Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
```

**staging.properties**

```
staging.wildfly.path=/Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
```

**production.properties**

```
production.wildfly.path=/Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
    <parentDirectory>${project.basedir}</parentDirectory>
    <skip.maven.wildfly>true</skip.maven.wildfly>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <wildfly.path>${local.wildfly.path}</wildfly.path>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <properties>
            <wildfly.path>${staging.wildfly.path}</wildfly.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <wildfly.path>${production.wildfly.path}</wildfly.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${parentDirectory}/local.properties</file>
                            <file>${parentDirectory}/staging.properties</file>
                            <file>${parentDirectory}/production.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <jboss-home>${wildfly.path}</jboss-home>
                <skip>${skip.maven.wildfly}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**childModule2/pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
    <parentDirectory>${project.basedir}/..</parentDirectory>
    <skip.maven.wildfly>false</skip.maven.wildfly>
</properties>
```

With the above, when I run `mvn wildfly:run`, it downloads the latest WildFly server and tries to run with that instead of the `local.wildfly.path`.

If I change the `local` profile so that it uses the path directly (instead of using `local.wildfly.path` then it works as expected.

I'm not sure if I don't have the properties plugin configured correctly or whether the parent/child module relationship is interfering with things somehow. I did notice the oddity that in IntelliJ it allows me to autocomplete the properties file value as in the below screenshot, but when it autocompletes it gives an error about not being able to resolve the symbol.

[image: IntelliJ allows autocomplete]
[image: IntelliJ complains about not being about to resolve value]

**UPDATE**

See comments section.

I realized that `mvn clean package wildfly:run` correctly grabs the right property values. But `mvn clean wildfly:run` and `mvn wildfly:run` do not grab the values.

I added the following to my parent `pom.xml`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <echos>
            <echo>Discovered WildFly Path: ${wildfly.path}</echo>
        </echos>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn wildfly:run`, it looks like it's getting the correct values as shown by the output below.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent                                                         [pom]
[INFO] child-jar                                                      [jar]
[INFO] child-war                                                      [war]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.mycompany:parent >-----------------------
[INFO] Building parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) > package @ parent >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:0.3.0:echo (default) @ parent ---
[INFO] Discovered WildFly Path: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) < package @ parent <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) @ parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.mycompany:child-jar >---------------------
[INFO] Building child-jar 1.0-SNAPSHOT                               [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) > package @ child-jar >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-jar/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-jar/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
... // Excluded test output here

Results :

Tests run: 40, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:0.3.0:echo (default) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] Discovered WildFly Path: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) < package @ child-jar <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) @ child-jar ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.mycompany:child-war >------------------------
[INFO] Building child-war 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) > package @ child-war >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ child-war ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ child-war ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 159 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 747 source files to /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
... // Excluded test output here

Results :

Tests run: 163, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [child-war] in [/Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/target/child-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1475 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/target/child-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:0.3.0:echo (default) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Discovered WildFly Path: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) < package @ child-war <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) @ child-war ---
[INFO] JAVA_HOME : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[INFO] JBOSS_HOME: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/IdeaProjects/myproject/child-war/target/wildfly-17.0.0.Final
```

But as shown by the last line, it ends up using the downloaded WildFly 17. In contrast, when I run `mvn clean package wildfly:run`, then (as shown below) the correct value is grabbed (last line).

```xml
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:0.3.0:echo (default) @ child-war ---
[INFO] Discovered WildFly Path: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) < package @ child-war <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:run (default-cli) @ child-war ---
[INFO] JAVA_HOME : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[INFO] JBOSS_HOME: /Users/snowyCoderGirl/wildfly-8.2.1.Final
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with a simple project (parent + child project, and using `echo-maven-plugin` to simply print the content of my property). Though, I'm facing the same autocomplete issue with IntelliJ (I think it is just confused). Could you try to add the `echo-maven-plugin` (https://github.com/khmarbaise/echo-maven-plugin/tree/de3da2d7#usage) to echo `${wildfly.path}` and check what's printed in your parent and your child builds?

Comment: This is a working example of `properties-maven-plugin` with a child module : https://github.com/norbjd/test-properties-maven-plugin/tree/06d2b74a. Could you check that your project structure is similar to this?

Comment: Thank you for commenting :) - I added the echo plugin and it's correctly outputting the values I want. Which I feel is confusing... but it's progress.

Comment: Found an oddity. I changed the echo plugin's `phase` to `package`. Now, when I run `mvn wildfly:run` it still fails (though the echo output is correct), but when I run `mvn clean package wildfly:run` it works. `mvn clean wildfly:run` fails.

Comment: Just realized I can remove the echo plugin and the same thing occurs. So somehow running `mvn clean package wildfly:run` works but `mvn wildfly:run` does not. WildFly seems to be running up to package itself. I'll update the ticket with the output.

Comment: I have never used wildfly plugin, but [from the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/2.0.1.Final/run-mojo.html#jbossHome), it looks like it can use the user property `jboss-as.home` (must be declared with other properties, like `skip.maven.wildfly`) instead of declaring `jboss-home` inside the plugin. Could you try to add the user property `<jboss-as.home>${wildfly.path}</jboss-as.home>` and remove `jboss-home` from the plugin configuration, and see what happens?

Comment: No luck. It still picks up the `target` version of the WildFly server.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong here :/ Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share the code with us, so we can try it locally and help you solve your issue?

Comment: It looks like you're hitting https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-70. What works for me with your configuration is if you run `mvn clean initialize wildfly:run` it should work. Of if you change the `<phase>` then just execute that phase explicitly instead.

Comment: @norbjd - Sorry for the delay. Here's a simple example: https://github.com/snowyCoderGirl/maven-wildfly-profiles-issue

Answer (score 1):

When running `mvn wildfly:run`, only the `run` goal of `wildfly-maven-plugin` is executed. It is executed with the following configuration :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
  <configuration>
    <jboss-home>${wildfly.path}</jboss-home>
    <skip>${skip.maven.wildfly}</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, the plugin expects `wildfly.path` property to be defined. But here, with `mvn wildfly:run` command, `wildfly.path` is not defined : properties from files **have not been read**, because `properties-maven-plugin` **have not been executed** (check the Maven logs to see that this plugin have not been called).

Therefore, since `wildfly.path` have an empty value, `wildfly-maven-plugin` acts as if this property was not set, thus downloading the latest version of Wildfly.

To ensure that `wildfly.path` property is set, you should ensure that `properties-maven-plugin` reads properties from files, by running :

```
mvn initialize wildfly:run
```

Since `properties-maven-plugin` is bound to the `initialize` phase, `wildfly.path` property will be set during `initialize` phase.

This explains also why `mvn package wildfly:run` works, because with this command, the `initialize` phase is run, as all phases before `package` phase.

Note that you could also run :

```
mvn wildfly:run -Dwildfly.path=/path/to/wildfly-8.2.0.Final
```

Here, `wildfly.path` is provided in the command so there is no need to read from a properties file.